# openweathermap showing unauthorized with api key

Tags: javascript, openweathermap

I have this:

```
<script>
        function gettingJSON(){
            $.getJSON("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=",function(json){
                console.log(JSON.stringify(json));
            });
        }
</script>
```

when i run this, and look at my console, i get this erorr:

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized) (weather, line 0)
```

my api key matches the one in the openweathermap dashboard, so wondering y its not acc working. Maybe i'm missing something. any ideaS?

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to put your api key in the query string.

```
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=[HERE]
```

Moreover it requires a couple of hours to be activated and ready to use.